# event is not null but _invocationList is null?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I thought that if I have this code:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
```

and the `PropertyChanged` event wasn't hooked, `ProeprtyChanged` would be `null`, but I'm getting a `PropertyChanged` that is not null and whose `_invocationList` member is `null` and whose `_invocationCount` member is 0. This (I think) is causing an ArgumentOutOfRangeException when I invoke `PropertyChanged(this, e)`. Any idea where could the problem be?

This is my stack trace from the `OnClick` event:

> at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.BindingsCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.BindingManagerBase.PushData(Boolean& success)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.PropertyManager.OnCurrentChanged(EventArgs ea)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.PropValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>      at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>      at System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor.OnValueChanged(Object component, EventArgs e)
>      at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.OnValueChanged(Object component, EventArgs e)
>      at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.OnINotifyPropertyChanged(Object component, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>      at Player.DataBaseManager.OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Juan Luis\My Dropbox\Documents\CodeWebScraper sin Player\WebScraperAndPlayer\Player\DataBaseManager2.cs:line 100
>      at Player.DataBaseManager.set_TableNames(List`1 value) in C:\Users\Juan Luis\My Dropbox\Documents\CodeWebScraper sin Player\WebScraperAndPlayer\Player\DataBaseManager2.cs:line 30
>      at Player.DataBaseManager.UpdateTableNames() in C:\Users\Juan Luis\My Dropbox\Documents\CodeWebScraper sin Player\WebScraperAndPlayer\Player\DataBaseManager2.cs:line 95
>      at Player.DataBaseManager.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlQuery) in C:\Users\Juan Luis\My Dropbox\Documents\CodeWebScraper sin Player\WebScraperAndPlayer\Player\DataBaseManager2.cs:line 336
>      at WebScraperAndPlayer.DataBaseEditor.deleteTableButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Juan Luis\My Dropbox\Documents\CodeWebScraper sin Player\WebScraperAndPlayer\BuilderForm2\Data\DataBaseEditor.cs:line 90
>      at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)

Comment: Where does the exception show up in the debugger?

Comment: at `PropertyChanged(this, e)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your stack trace

> at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) at System.Windows.Forms.BindingsCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) at System.Windows.Forms.BindingManagerBase.PushData(Boolean& success) at

This isn't a problem with the event wiring, something else is messed up in your data binding.

Comment: I saw that, but still wouldn't be a problem to get an event that is not null and whose invocation list is null?

Comment: @jsoldi Why are you so focused on the invocation list? As far as I'm concerned, that's behind the scenes plumbing that I couldn't care less about. Check your event code, in particular anywhere you use an ArrayList.

Comment: @jsoldi: No, it's not. And @Mike Caron nailed why you shouldn't care. I don't know what `_invocationList` is, but I know that it being `null` is not necessarily a problem.

Comment: OK, OK. I'll try to do a deeper debug.

Answer (score 1):

> System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)

That was the PropertyChanged(this, e) call.  It isn't the cause of the exception, your stack trace went well beyond this.  Unfortunately into code you didn't write, it's part of the Winforms binding plumbing.  Something is screwed up with the binding.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I had a data table editor that had a `TablesList` property bound to a list of data tables in a data base manager object. In its `set` accessor I checked to see if the table still existed in the list and if it didn't the editor closed and removed the data binding from the data base manager. So, while the internals of .NET were looping through the objects bound to `TablesList`, one of them removed itself from the list. But .NET doesn't notice this change because of the way the loop is written:

```
int numLinks = Bindings.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < numLinks; i++) { 
    if (Bindings[i].PushData()) { 
        success = false;
    } 
}
```

I was basically removing the binding from inside the `PushData()` call. My solution was to attach an event handler to the `PropertyChanged` event and check the table list there. Apparently whatever loop .NET uses to loop through the invocation list of events let you remove an event while in the loop.

I guess the moral would be: Never remove a `Binding` that updates a property from the `set` accessor of that property; but is OK to remove an event handler from the event handler itself. Right?